# How can I make a Button with multiple content values?

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

My goal is to make a Button that has two Content values.

Imagine a Scrabble tile as a button: it has the large letter in the center and a small number in the lower right.  This is the effect I am going for.

I made a button that has two ContentPresenter objects in it, and I have given each of the ContentPresenters a different style.  However, I have not found a way to give each of the presenters a separate value (ie, if I set the Content of the button to "X" then both ContentPresenters show "X", albeit in different styles).

How can I achieve my objective?  I'm guessing my approach is completely wrong....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah... I think I know what to do now.  I should be making my own control rather than modifying a Button.  This would have been obvious to me had I been working in WinForms, but for some reason all this Xaml is making me stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Expander sample ControlTemplate at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296.aspx

Expander is a subclass of HeaderedContentControl, it has two "contents": Header and Content

The control template has two ContentPresenter elements, the ContentPresenter that is not bound to the default content property is defined as:

<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />

If you need to use a Button and you don't want to add another property for the second content you can use an attached property and data bind the second ContentPresnter Content property to it.

Answer (score 0):

I delaled with creating UserControl with multiple 'content slots' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029955/wpf-template-or-usercontrol-with-2-or-more-contentpresenters-to-present-conte) - it's better than deriving from HeaderedControl as you aren't limited in the number of slots.

Sample usage:

```
<Window x:Class="TkMVVMContainersSample.Services.TaskEditDialog.ItemEditView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Common="clr-namespace:TkMVVMContainersSample.Views.Common"
    Title="ItemEditView"
    >
    <Common:DialogControl>
        <Common:DialogControl.Heading>
            <!-- Heading string goes here -->
        </Common:DialogControl.Heading>
        <Common:DialogControl.Control>
            <!-- Concrete dialog's content goes here -->
        </Common:DialogControl.Control>
        <Common:DialogControl.Buttons>
            <!-- Concrete dialog's buttons go here -->
        </Common:DialogControl.Buttons>
    </Common:DialogControl>

</Window>
```